# Destructuring the t method out of i18next breaks it

Tags: node.js, i18next

I want to translate my node.js application using [i18next](https://github.com/i18next/i18next).
In the documentation and examples the translations are made like this (supposing i18next is already initialized properly) :

```js
const i18next = require("i18next")
console.log(i18next.t("key"))
```

I have a big quantity of text to translate at various places, so I would like to be able to save time by destructuring the `t` method like this :

```js
const { t } = require("i18next")
console.log(t("key"))
```

But I get the following error : `TypeError: Cannot read property 'translator' of undefined`. It looks like the method is using the other properties of the i18next object, causing its destructuring to break it.

Is there any workaround?

Comment: You'd need to bind the `this` context to `t`. I'm not really sure it's really much of an improvement, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't verified this, but you should be able to do something like this

```javascript
const i18next = require("i18next")
const t = i18next.t.bind(i18next);
console.log(t("key"))
```

I would suggest some better naming than t though...